# Create VIM Keybinding executing two commands and ranges (count)

Tags: vim, key-bindings

I am using [Slimux](https://github.com/epeli/slimux) and often use range modifiers to send code to a REPL. The keyboard shortcut ",s" sends a new line to the REPL, executes the commands () and advances one line (j),

```
map <Leader>s :SlimuxREPLSendLine<CR>j
```

If I use ranges, e.g. "5,s", this sends 5 lines of code to the REPL, but only advances one line (j) instead of 5j. I tried playing around with :exe and v.count1 to achieve this, but was not very successful.

Can anyone provide a code example (and explanation how this works)?

Comment: Needs to migrate to vi.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
noremap <Leader>s :SlimuxREPLSendLine<Bar>execute 'normal!' v:count1 . 'j'<CR>
```

It depends on the `:SlimuxREPLSendLine` command having been defined with `-bar` to be able to append another command to it.

<sup>PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.</sup>